# Azure Queue Storage - SAS permissions without delete

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

I have a storage-account used by multiple users. The access should be limited by a SAS-Token. The client needs the rights to confirm that his message is delivered and processed. He isn't allowed to update or delete the messages.

Which permissions do I need to set for my SAS-Token?

As far as I know it should be "Read", "Write" and "Add"?, but for reading messages "Process" is needed, which includes deletes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Queue Permission]

See whether permissions setting above is eligible for your requirement.

For queue messages, Read permission allows us to [Peek messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues#peek-at-the-next-message)(the example is to get one next message, we can also use `queue.PeekMessages` to peek all messages in queue), we don't need Process permission.

Add permission lets us to add messages in queue(`queue.AddMessage`). As for the Write Permission, it's to create new queues. If you want grant this permission, also click on Container of Allowed resource types.